# TYPO3: extension with both backend module and frontend plugin

Tags: frontend, typo3

I am trying to create an extension ('XML Uploader') with a backend module and a frontend plugin also.

The backend module will be used for managing xml files (upload, validate against a DTD), and the frontend plugin should be used for displaying the uploaded xmls.

The problem is with the frontend part: 
I followed 
[the basic extension tutorial](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/player_profile_basic/0.0.8/view/) - added a new page, created a content element of type 'Insert plugin' - but when trying to add a new record, the type 'XML Uploader' does not appear in the list of new record types. Moreover, the changes made to class.tx_xmluploader_pi1.php have no effect.

So how should I work with the frontend plugin? Or would it be better to create a separate extension instead?

Any help would be very much appreciated.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. When creating your table with the extension kickstarter you must check the "Allowed on pages:" checkbox to allow records from this table to be created on regular pages.
2. If your changes have no effect, it could be that the page is cached by typo3. In that case you can clear or disable the cache with the admin panel or in the page configuration menu.

Comment: 2. Cleared the cache, but still nothing. I think there might be a problem with the typoscript setup, but I have to read more about this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the static template of your extension (I presume you used the kickstarter or extension_builder):

go to the your template, in the object browser you should see something like:

```
plugin.tx_xmluploader_pi1 = USER
```

if you can't find it, edit your template (edit/modify => edit whole template record) and add your extension template in the tab 'Includes'

Additionally, check your ext_localconf.php for the line

```
t3lib_extMgm::addPItoST43($_EXTKEY, 'pi1/class.tx_xmluploader_pi1.php', '_pi1', 'list_type', 0);
```

This is where your FE plugin is being registered.

Comment: This is wrong. Static templates is just for Typoscript to be included in an another style. It's not to make the plugin visible at all.

Comment: You're right, the plugin is registered in ext_localconf.php. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.. I eventually created a page and added a template record with the following setup: `page = PAGE
page {
 10 < plugin.tx_xmldisplayer_pi1
}
`